# GWT: Client procedure and rpc request are always called several times with multiple thread id

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

For some client side procedures, I implement remote logging to log the calling of the procedure. The log is printed several times with different thread id, even though the procedure is only called once. Some rpc requests are sent to the sever a few times which causes some database session problem. Is it normal? Is there anyway to avoid it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal, and suggests there is a bug on your client causing it to send the same call more than once. Try adding logging on the client where you invoke the RPC call, and possibly add breakpoints to confirm why it is being called twice.

My best guess with no other information would be that you have more than one event handler wired up to the same button, or something like that.

--

More specifically, your servlet container starts multiple threads to handle incoming requests - if two requests come in close succession, they might be handled by different threads.

As you noted, this can cause problems with a database, where two simultaneous calls could be made to change the same data, especially if you have some checks to ensure that a servlet call cannot accidentally overwrite some newer data. This is almost certainly a bug in your client code, and debugging it should start there.